# Passing data from Flex to Java

Tags: apache-flex

How do I pass a dataprovider of a full datagrid from flex to java services. So that I can save data from the datagrid into a database?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a server side service in java and connect to it from your Flex app using [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html) for SOAP Requests, or [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html) for AMF, or [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html) for SOAP requests.

Comment: can you send me an example with remoteobject

Comment: You can read the documentation and find examples there.  I linked to it.  If you are having problems, please edit your question to provide some details and code as to what your specific problems are.